# norm of an algebraic number with abs value smaller than 1

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic number and $\alpha = \alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ its conjugates and $N(\alpha) = \prod_i \alpha_i$ its norm.
Is it true that $|\alpha| < 1 \Rightarrow |N(\alpha)| < 1$ and if so why?
(|| denotes the complex absolut value)
Thanks.

Comment: Let $\alpha=2-\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the special case of algebraic integers, the answer is no in an extremely strong sense. Note that if what you say is true, it would imply that if $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$, then $|\alpha_i| = 1$ for all conjugates of $\alpha$.

**Proposition:** Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer all of whose conjugates have absolute value $1$. Then $\alpha$ is a root of unity.

*Proof.* Let $\alpha = \alpha_1$ have conjugates $\alpha_1, ... \alpha_d$ and let
$$f_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^d (x - \alpha_i^n).$$

The coefficient of $x^k$ in $f_n(x)$ is an integer of absolute value at most ${d \choose k}$ for all values of $n$, so it follows that $f_n(x)$ can only be one of a finite list of polynomials. Hence there exist $m, n$ such that $f_n(x) = f_m(x)$, and this relation implies that some pair of powers of $\alpha_1$ are identical.

Thus if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer that is not a root of unity, some conjugate of $\alpha$ has absolute value greater than $1$, and if $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$ then some conjugate of $\alpha$ has absolute value less than $1$.

Comment: Historical note: the Proposition is due to Kronecker.

Answer (score 5):

No. For example, let $\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Then $|\alpha|<1$ but $N(\alpha)=1$.

Comment: More generally, if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer then $N(\alpha)$ is a nonzero integer, so must have absolute value at least $1$. In other words, if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer with $|\alpha| < 1$ then some conjugate of $\alpha$ has absolute value greater than $1$. Conversely, if $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$ and $|\alpha| > 1$ then some conjugate of $\alpha$ has absolute value less than $1$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Exactly. For a second I was thinking that we needed reciprocals of [Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number), but that's not necessary - your explanation is the most general.

Answer (score 0):

Of course $$P_c(z) = z^3-2cz^2-c$$ has three roots, let us call them $a$,$b$ and $\bar b$. The roots $b$ and $\bar b$ lie within the unit circle but the root $a$ escapes along the real axis to infinity as the parameter $c$ increase from $1$ to $\infty$. Note that these are algebraic integers with norm $c$, two of which have "absolute value" below 1 (and getting smaller) and one of which has as big absolute value close to $2c$.

[image: plot]

The geometric interpretation of algebraic norm (in some number field) is quite unrelated to the metric of the complex plane. You actually form a higher dimensional lattice spanned by an integral basis and the norm of an algebraic number, expressed in terms of the basis, is the distance of that point to the origin.

Comment: $2c$ is the $\it trace$, not the norm. The norm is $c$.